# WebView not receiving error even if server sends back an error

Tags: android, http-headers, webview

The webpage that I'm trying to access is sending back a 403 error. I's expecting WebViewClient to receive an error, but it doesn't. Is it not supposed to get error?

```
engine.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        boolean error = false;
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {

            //IT DOESN'T COME HERE even IF SERVER SENDS BACK 403 ERROR
        }
    });
```

It seams like, I'll have to read the response using HttpRequest and parse the response to check what's going on. Is there any other way to do this? Can I check headers from within the WebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to implement the requirement using two requests. First request to check if credentials are ok and that there's no error(using HttpURLConnection). Only if the response is OK do I load the webview.

```
protected Void doInBackground(final String... url) {
        boolean failed = false;
        int error = 0;

        try {
            URL urlToLoad = new URL(url[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlToLoad
                    .openConnection();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (response != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                error = response;
                failed = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!failed) {
            webView.loadUrl(url[0]);
        } else {
            handler.post(hideProgressRunnable);
            connecting = false;
            showError(ErrorMap.getErrorForHttpCode(error));
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: sad but true.  Consider starring the Android issue for this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32755&q=webview%20error&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars